# Open a page from a URL derived from a SQL query

Tags: javascript, java, sql, sql-server, url

I want to be able to use JavaScript to open a URL, however the URL has been made up from a SQL query as it is different on every page (entity). I was wondering if it was possible, was thinking something along the lines of

```
function opencs(ev)
{
    window.open('{sql query}');
}
```

The SQL statement is

```
SELECT
https://www.xcweather.co.uk/forecast/' + (SUBSTRING({[postal_code], 1, CHARINDEX(' '[Postal_Code])))
FROM TABLE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have your backend load the SQL data and output it on the page as JS variable. In PHP you'd do `echo "<script> var location = '$location'; </script>";` You can now simply insert that into the URL and request it.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL will be executed on the server, but the javascript is running on the client. That means that the javascript can't execute the SQL. You will need to execute the SQL on the server, then pass the results (in this case, the URLs) to the client.